# Is there any downside to choosing MYSQL instead of SQL server on visual studio 2010?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, visual-studio

I am new to visual studio, I want to develop a database application with it, I will prefer to use `MYSQL` database which I am very familiar with. I will like to know if there is any downside to it, and if I can successfully deploy the application and the `MYSQL` database together.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean 'deploy'. Deploring your own application seems rather... pointless.

Comment: I was just playing golf yesterday with a guy who says his company uses ASP.net w/ mysql

Comment: Have a look at this point outlining some of the differences.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757820/c-sharp-mysql-vs-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assume that you are going to deploy your application using .net.
Well, i don't see any issue with .net + mysql

Comment: Not that this was a constructive question in the first place, but this answer doesn't really add any value. Could you point to examples that support your opinion?